# Typo3 Fluid: What is the correct way to render flux:flexform.field.wizard.link?

Tags: typo3, fluid, flux, viewhelper, fedext

I'm working with the Typo3 6.1 and Fluid templates, using the [fedext.net](http://fedext.net) set of tools.
I have the content element back-end template defined like this:

```
{namespace flux=Tx_Flux_ViewHelpers}
{namespace v=Tx_Vhs_ViewHelpers}
<f:layout name="Content" />
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:flux="http://fedext.net/ns/flux/ViewHelpers"
     xmlns:v="http://fedext.net/ns/vhs/ViewHelpers"
     xmlns:f="http://fedext.net/ns/fluid/ViewHelpers">

...

<flux:flexform.object name="item">
    <flux:flexform.field.input name="url">
        <flux:flexform.field.wizard.link />
    </flux:flexform.field.input>
</flux:flexform.object>
```

And then I'm rendering it in the front-end like this

```
<f:link.external uri="{section.item.url}">
    {section.item.url}
</f:link.external>
```

And the problem is that link backend wizards allows user to set the links like `http://www.google.com/ _blank - Google` which stands for `href target css-class title` and that ends up in the following front-end HTML render:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/ _blank - Google">
    http://www.google.com/ _blank - Google
</a>
```

I wonder is there already any ViewHelper which allows to render link widget data properly? Or I should implement one myself? I already checked these docs:

- [FluidViewHelperReference](http://docs.typo3.org/flow/TYPO3FlowDocumentation/stable/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartV/FluidViewHelperReference.html#f-link-external)
- [LinkViewHelper](https://fedext.net/viewhelpers/vhs/Page/LinkViewHelper.html)

and I've sticked to the first one, but it is a bit simpler than what I really need.
Probably there is also a ViewHelper which can split the link data by space character and then I can render the link but sound like a not reliable work-around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is that flux and fluidcontent themselves dont provide a ViewHelper for those.

You have to use a foreign ViewHelper like [this one](http://lbrmedia.net/codebase/Eintrag/extbase-typolinkviewhelper/) . I added [a variant](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/vhs/blob/master/Classes/ViewHelpers/Uri/TypolinkViewHelper.php) of it to the VHS ViewHelper collection extension. Similar to the fluid core, we added 2 new ViewHelpers to the VHS companion extension (v:link.typolink & v:uri.typolink):

After installing it, import the Namespace to your Template like this:

`{namespace v=Tx_Vhs_ViewHelpers}`

and use it in your template:

`<v:uri.typolink parameter="{parameter: section.item.url}" />`

That should do the trick.

Additionally, as this only renders the uri generated by typolink, there's a second very similar ViewHelper in `vhs` you can use to generate links:

`<v:link.typolink parameter="{parameter: section.item.url}">Beautiful link</v:link.typolink>`

Thx to kimomat for pointing this out in the answer below.

Comment: I like to use `v:link.typolink` but is it possible to get just the title of the url target ?

Comment: There is a viewhelper for that. You need to know the pid though. https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/vhs/blob/development/Classes/ViewHelpers/Page/InfoViewHelper.php

Comment: thanks! `<v:page.info pageUid="{section.item.url}" field="title"/>`

Answer (score 0):

If i render the example in a fluidcontent Main Section (TYPO3 6.2, VHS 1.9.1, Fluidcontent 4.0.0) the ViewHelper only outputs the link url, no link.

```
<p><v:uri.typolink configuration="{parameter: '13', additionalParams: '&print=1', title: 'Follow the link'}">Click Me!</v:uri.typolink></p>
```

This code will render:

```
<p>/products/?print=1</p>
```

The PageUid 13 is the products page.
I would have expected a a tag.

Ok, i got it. I need the ViewHelper v:link.typolink:

```
<v:link.typolink configuration="{parameter: '13', additionalParams: '&print=1', title: 'Follow the link'}">Click Me!</v:link.typolink>
```